# Query for displaying count per type for each date in range

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using PostgreSQL, I have two tables (lunch_order & lunch_list).
The two table is connected by lunch_id

*What I want to do is to display a query that contain total count from each type of lunch for each day in a month*

**lunch_order**

[image: lunch_order table]

**lunch_list**
[image]

**This is my current query syntax:**

```
select  true_lunch_name as Lunch_Name, 
count(*) filter (where order_date = '2021-12-21' ) as day1,
count(*) filter (where order_date = '2021-12-22' ) as day2,
count(*) filter (where order_date = '2021-12-23' ) as day3
.....
from project1.lunch_order ord inner join  project1.lunch_list list on ord.lunch_type = list.lunch_id 
where order_date between '2021-12-21' and '2021-12-31' and list.is_active = 'true' and list.lunch_id != '1'
group by true_lunch_name,lunch_id order by lunch_id asc
```

**This is the result with only 3 days selected for now:**

[image]

But I was wondering, is there another ways to do it.

Because If I do it like this, I need to make 4 kind of queries for each type of months (28days, 29days, 30days, and 31days)

Comment: is it month wise?

Comment: yes, month wise.

Comment: will you use this query in a report? if yes please prepare 31 row for each month and enable or disable rows as per month.

Comment: yes, for an excel report. What do you mean by enable and disable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Single SQL will work for all months. This is for the current example. You can adjust the number and dates.

SQL:

```
SELECT lunch_name,
       Sum(day1) "day1",
       Sum(day2) "day2",
       Sum(day3) "day3",
       Sum(day4) "day4",
       Sum(day5) "day5",
       Sum(day6) "day6",
       Sum(day7) "day7",
       Sum(day8) "day8"
FROM   (SELECT lunch_name,
               CASE
                 WHEN Extract(day FROM order_date) = 21 THEN cnt
               END "day1",
               CASE
                 WHEN Extract(day FROM order_date) = 22 THEN cnt
               END "day2",
               CASE
                 WHEN Extract(day FROM order_date) = 23 THEN cnt
               END "day3",
               CASE
                 WHEN Extract(day FROM order_date) = 24 THEN cnt
               END "day4",
               CASE
                 WHEN Extract(day FROM order_date) = 25 THEN cnt
               END "day5",
               CASE
                 WHEN Extract(day FROM order_date) = 26 THEN cnt
               END "day6",
               CASE
                 WHEN Extract(day FROM order_date) = 27 THEN cnt
               END "day7",
               CASE
                 WHEN Extract(day FROM order_date) = 28 THEN cnt
               END "day8"
        FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT lunch_name,
                                order_date,
                                Count(lunch_name)
                                  OVER(
                                    partition BY lunch_name, order_date
                                    ORDER BY order_date) cnt
                FROM   lunch_order lo
                       INNER JOIN lunch_list ll
                               ON ll.lunch_id = lo.lunch_type) inline_view)
       final_inline_view
GROUP  BY lunch_name;
```

Output:

```
 lunch_name | day1 | day2 | day3 | day4 | day5 | day6 | day7 | day8
------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------
 ccc        |      |      |    1 |    1 |      |      |    1 |    1
 bbb        |    2 |    1 |      |      |      |      |      |    1
(2 rows)
```

Setup:

```
create table lunch_order(lunch_type int , order_date date);
create table lunch_list(lunch_id int,lunch_name varchar(10));
insert into lunch_order values
,(20,'2021-12-22'),(22,'2021-12-23'),(22,'2021-12-24'),(22,'2021-12-27'),(20,'2021-12-28'),(22,'2021-12-28');
insert into lunch_list values(1,'aaa'),(20,'bbb'),(22,'ccc'),(23,'ddd'),(24,'eee');


postgres=# select * from lunch_order;
 lunch_type | order_date
------------+------------
         20 | 2021-12-21
         20 | 2021-12-22
         22 | 2021-12-23
         22 | 2021-12-24
         22 | 2021-12-27
         22 | 2021-12-28
         20 | 2021-12-21
         20 | 2021-12-28
(8 rows)

postgres=# select * from lunch_list;
 lunch_id | lunch_name
----------+------------
        1 | aaa
       20 | bbb
       22 | ccc
       23 | ddd
       24 | eee
(5 rows)
```

Comment: true, this is an another way of doing it